# Web-Api OData Controller return single record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, endpoint

I have a OData-Controller like this (shortened code):

```
    public class FooController : ODataController
    {
        [Queryable]
        public IEnumerable<Foo> Get()
        {       
            return ...;
        }

        [Queryable]
        public SingleResult<Foo> GetById([FromODataUri] int id)
        {
            return SingleResult.Create<Foo>(...);
        }
```

I call `/myprefix/foo` in the browser an the the `Get()` method is invoked.

Now I call `/myprefix/foo(1)` in the browser an the the `Get()` method is always invoked. 
But I want call the `GetById()` method.

How can I get run the `GetById()`?
Thanks

Comment: I found the solution. I changed the "int id" to "int key" in the GetById. Now it works.

Comment: good work Boqus, it helped me too. add it as an answer

Answer (score 7):

I confirm that the solution provided in the comment is **working**.

Change your method parameter using **key** as parameter name:

```
public Unit GetBook([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return db.Books.Single(b => b.BookID == key);
}
```

and it'll accept this kind of requests, passing the record primary key:

```
server/odata/Books(34)
```

Answer (score 2):

Default OData routing conventions in Web API look for actions like:

`GetFoo([FromODataUri] int id)` (that is..."Get" + EntityType name)

OR

`Get([FromODataUri] int id)`

so make sure to change your action to either of the above.

If you do not like the above convention, you can write a custom `IODataRoutingConvention`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the GetById() method.

Just you call by **/api/foo/GetById?id=**

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in case the route name is different from the entity set is add the ODataRoute attribute:

For querying an IEnumerable you would then use the attribute:

```
[ODataRoute("Foo")]
public IEnumerable<Foo> Get()
```

For querying the single result you then would use the following syntax:

```
[ODataRoute("Foo({key})")]
public SingleResult<Foo> GetById([FromODataUri] int key)
```

Besides this, I guess it is also preferrable nowadays to use EnableQuery instead of Queryable.